# Spring AOP aspect with annotations is not working for base class

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, annotations, aop

I have annotation defined as below

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface OTPFlow {
}
```

And class A defined as below

```
public abstract class A {
  @OTPFlow
  public ModelAndView doSomething() {
    //do something and return ModelAndView
  }
}
```

Class B is a controller defined as below

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"/someurl"})
public class B extends A {
  @RequestMapping(value = {"/get"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
  public ModelAndView get(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return doSomething();
  }
}
```

Aspect is defined as

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class OTPAspect {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OTPAspect.class);

@Pointcut("@annotation(OTPFlow)")
public void OTPFlow() {}

@Around("OTPFlow()")
public Object checkOTP(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    try {
        logger.info("Inside Aspect");
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

The problem is when i access "/someurl/get" url, the aspect does not execute. But when i annotate "get" method of class B, aspect executes.

So basically, annotated methods of superclass does not invoke Aspect.

What is the issue? Is there any other way to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Spring uses proxies, only method calls INTO the object are intercepted, you are internally calling a method.

Comment: There's one sort of "work around" here that can be done, without resorting to full AspectJ. Just create a "prototype scoped" bean, that gives you a way to sort of create a temporary proxy (by instantiating an instance of the bean), and then if you have the methods on this bean targeted with pointcuts the instantiated bean will be its own proxy and therefore the AOP *will* get called correctly. Obviously you would only use this in limited circumstances, and not make it a core part of your architecture, but in cases where you need what Spring AOP can't provide, this "prototype" trick can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to offer an alternative to what M. Deinum and Marios have said correctly: Use AspectJ instead of Spring AOP. AspectJ does not rely on proxies, is faster, more powerful and integrates nicely with Spring as described in Spring manual, [Section 9.8, Using AspectJ with Spring applications](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj). With AspectJ what you want to do works out of the box.

Comment: Well that depends :). You can use AspectJ with spring but still rely on proxies. What you mean is full blown AspectJ with either load or compile time weaving.

Comment: No, I mean AspectJ when I say AspectJ, see my link. The proxy-based framework you are talking about is *not* AspectJ, it is Spring AOP, an "AOP lite" approach built into Spring, and just happens to use a subset of the AspectJ pointcut syntax.

Comment: Well it is not only the AspectJ syntax that is used you can also use AspectJ aspects with it. Although indeed for a subset (`execution` and the special `bean` pointcuts) of the pointcuts available to full blown AspectJ. Which is what makes it a bit vague on where AspectJ ends and Spring AOP starts.. (Historically it was based only on the `aopalliance` stuff).

Comment: I do know that. But I think the demarcation line is not vague at all: AspectJ starts where LTW or CTW are used and ends where the proxy approach is used. Dynamic proxy (Java or CGLIB) *always* means Spring AOP and AspectJ *never* uses proxies. AOP Alliance syntax is, as the term implies, just syntax.

Comment: IMHO it isn't  especially because you can just use AspectJ aspects with proxies. But that just gives you a subset of the full functionality of AspectJ. But alas we can agree to disagree :).

Comment: I am no expert on this issue, but after going through [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn) I can understand that AspectJ and Spring AOP are two separate ways to implement AOP. AspectJ is a complete implementation, while Spring AOP is partial. [Aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming#Terminology) is a terminology in AOP, so saying AspectJ aspects can be used with Spring AOP is like comparing apple with orange ;)

Answer (score 2):

What happens when spring applies the aspect, is that spring creates proxies that wrap your controller instance to intercept calls and add the aspect behaviour before calling the instance method. This has the effect, that any call to "this" from within your controller instance is directly invoked on that instance and will not be intercepted by the wrapping proxy. Therefore, the "get" method is called on the proxy class, which in turn will call the "get" method of the controller instance, and when the latter tries to call the "doSomething" method it will not pass through the proxied "doSomething", but through the internal one.

The way to handle this situation is to apply aspects directly to the methods of your class that will be externally called, in your case directly on the "get" method instead of the "doSomething"